# How to set CALayer as the contents of SCNMaterial

Tags: ios, calayer, scenekit

I'm new to SceneKit. I'm trying to set a texture which view is drawn by code on a `SCNSphere`. The custom view looks like this:

```
class CustomView : UIView {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let centerX = self.bounds.width / 2
        let centerY = self.bounds.height / 2

        // fill background
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.layer.frame)

        // draw axises
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)

        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, 0, centerY)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, self.bounds.width, centerY)
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx)

        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, centerX, 0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, centerX, self.bounds.height)
        CGContextStrokePath(ctx)
    }
}
```

The view looks like this:
[image]

To set this view as a texture of a `SCNSphere`, I took the `layer` of it and set it to the `contents` of the `firstMaterial`.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sceneView = self.view as SCNView
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 4)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 1)
        let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = customView.layer

        let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
    }
}
```

I expect the layer to cover all the sphere, but this is what I get:

[image]

Only some part of the sphere is being drawn. If I comment-out all the custom drawing code, and set `customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` instead, then I get the whole sphere being covered white.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Maybe something involving UV mapping / projection?